# Print data from MySQL in Flask with same id

Tags: html, mysql, for-loop, flask, session

This is my HTML table:

```html
{% block content %}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
        <th>Transffered Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ account['from1'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ account['to1'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ account['amount1'] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my flask program for it:

```py
@app.route('/user_history')
def user_history():
    # Check if account exists using MySQL

    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

    # Check if user is loggedin
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        # We need all the account info for the user so we can display it on the profile page
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM inforamtion WHERE id = %s', [session['id']])
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        # Show the profile page with account info
        return render_template('user_history.html', account=account)
    # User is not loggedin redirect to login page
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

This is MySQL table:

```
   id   to1     from1   amount1
    2   saurav  vishal  3500
    2   yogi    vishal  1200
    3   sandhya jaywant 780
    3   sangu   jaywant 8700
    7   mayur   Gaurav  750
```

but it is printing only the first table, i.e

```
saurav  vishal  3500
```

and not the second one. Do I need a for loop for it, or are there any other solutions?

Comment: session id is one number say  2 so it would return only the second row, so if  you only get the first row, it is because you have always the id 1 and we can't see where you set the session['id']

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest of the problem, but I can tell you that it is very bad practice to have multiple/different rows with the same `id`.

Comment: notice the "fetchone()" so you just get one row from search result.

Comment: More likely than not, your loop may be skipping the remaining rows with the same `id` because `id` is being used as a primary key (i.e. the way your database keeps track of which rows are which), and once it has already processed a row with `2` or `3`, it moves on to the next key.

Comment: so what should i do now. what changes i have to do in my program